# Specifying constraint on all nodes of a variable length relationship using Cypher

Tags: neo4j

I have java classes and modules in a Neo4j database as nodes. There are two types of relationship between them: classes can depend on other classes and modules can contain classes. I would like to create a query which retrieves all the transitive dependencies of a class in it's module.

I was trying this query:

```
MATCH (startNode:Class {name:"x.y.Foo"})-[*:DEPENDS_ON]->
      (c:Class)<-[:CONTAINS]-(:Module { name :"container"}) return c;
```

The problem is that it retrieves classes in `container` which can be reached through classes outside `container` starting from `x.y.Foo`. This is not only incorrect, but painfully slow as well. Is it possible to phrase what I want in Cypher?

The number of nodes is 11575 and relationships is 65215 and I am using Neo4j 2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
MATCH p=(startNode:Class {name:"x.y.Foo"})-[*:DEPENDS_ON]->
      (c:Class)<-[:CONTAINS]-(m:Module { name :"container"}) 
WHERE ALL( n IN nodes(p)[1..-2] WHERE (n)<-[:CONTAINS]-(m))
RETURN c;
```

Another option would be to tag them with the module as label, then the check would be more efficient.

```
MATCH p=(startNode:Class {name:"x.y.Foo"})-[*:DEPENDS_ON]->
      (c:Class:`module:container`)<-[:CONTAINS]-(m:Module { name :"container"}) 
WHERE ALL( n IN nodes(p)[1..-2] WHERE (n:`module:container`))
RETURN c;
```

If you are interested in more work around this, check out this [blog post](http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/05/graph-databases-and-software-metrics.html).

Comment: The query doesn't want to finish... I think there is something "wrong" with my database, because no query finishes in reasonable time which contains unbounded variable length relationship, even if the start node is a non existent class.